# Is that the fact that the only possible finite (multiplicative) subgroup of the field $\mathbb{C}$ can only be those which is formed by root

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, cyclic-groups

I have just learnt a theorem that says:

> For the group of invertible elements $F^*$ of a field $F$, its finite subgroup is cyclic.

And an example is that for $F=\mathbb{C}$, we have the group generated by n-th roots of unity finite subgroups, and hence cyclic.

So I am now considering if the only finite subgroup of $\Bbb C^*$ are group generated by the n-th root of unity. If so, how may I prove that there is no other finite subgroup? If not, may I please ask for some other example?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking for, or the theorem that you learnt. Is it that the multiplicative group of every FINITE field is cyclic? or every FINITE subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$ is cyclic?

Comment: The correct claim is: any **finite** subgroup of the multiplicative group of *any* field is cyclic.

Comment: @Wore I am asking to determine the finite subgroup of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @PropositionX You surely meant that you're asking to determine the finite subgroup**s** of $\;\Bbb C^*\;$ ...it has infinitely many such subgroups, whereas the additive group $\;\Bbb C\;$ has none but the trivial one.

Comment: Isn't it obvious  that a cyclic subgroup of order $n$ in ${\mathbb C}^*$ consists of $n$-th roots of unity?

Comment: @DerekHolt I would say it is obvious after DonAntonio's answer. Before that, it's just "easy to show".

Comment: Maybe, but it is really just the definition of a cyclic group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\;C\;$ is a *finite* subgroup of $\;\Bbb C^*\;$ , then there exists

$$n\in\Bbb N\;\;\;s.t.\;\;\;\text{for all}\;\;\;c\in C\;,\;\;c^n=1$$

Comment: So is that correct that: Every element in a finite subgroup should always have finite multiplicative order, so the elements in the subgroup can only be roots of unity. And as if $n_1\ne n_2$, the product of 2 roots of unity does not give another root of unity, so we can only have subgroups generated by a single nth roots of unity?

Comment: @PropositionX Yes to your first question (obviously), and also its conclusion. Why do you think the product of two roots of unity cannot be a root of unity again? In fact, they **must be**, otherwise they cannot belong in a *multiplicative group* ...Even if you meant "two roots of unity of *different order*", their product is again a root of unity of order the roots' orders' common multiple.

Comment: Oh I see, I do mean different order and forgot the common multiple case. It is clear now. Thanks for patience!